# PHP e json como imprimir?

Tags: php, json, parse

Alguém poderia me ajudar a imprimir cada uma desses elementos deste Json usando php.

> {"data":{"charges":[{"code":30013193,"dueDate":"05/09/2017","checkoutUrl":"https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/checkout/985FFB59969D9F117D47FD7D1881880E","link":"https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=60370:m:9675cf45e010be056a06bdef6e0f478bd75f435ce9cda7d0cf5b9afdfc6fefc5","payNumber":"BOLETO TESTE"}]},"success":true}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php):

> [`json_decode( string $string, bool $assoc_array = false )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/json_decode/)

---

***Exemplo minimo***

> `$json = '{"data":{"charges":[{"code":30013193,"dueDate":"05/09/2017","checkoutUrl":"https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/checkout/985FFB59969D9F117D47FD7D1881880E",
>   "link":"https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=60370:m:9675cf45e010be056a06bdef6e0f478bd75f435ce9cda7d0cf5b9afdfc6fefc5","payNumber":"BOLETO TESTE"}]},"success":true}';`

```
$value = (json_decode($json, true));

echo $value['data']['charges'][0]['code'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $value['data']['charges'][0]['dueDate'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $value['data']['charges'][0]['checkoutUrl'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $value['data']['charges'][0]['link'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $value['data']['charges'][0]['payNumber'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $value['success'];
echo PHP_EOL;
```

[***Exemplo ONLINE***](https://repl.it/KeQG/10)

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)
- [JSON to PHP Using json_decode](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php)